# How can I get my bluetooth headset's microphone working?

Tags: bluetooth, input-devices, microphone, headset

I have a Neurosky Mindset that doubles as a bluetooth headset. Bluetooth picks up the device fine and I have audio working. In sound preferences for input devices the headset isn't listed so I'm unable to get my mic working. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I have a different headset but the same bug on Ubuntu 11.10.
Did you manage to solve this?
There is also a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902572) for this.

Comment: I did manage to figure it out, although not a great solution. For some reason if I switched the sound to mono I was able to get the microphone working.

Answer (score 2):

OP has solved the problem themselves and posted as a comment

> I did manage to figure it out, although not a great solution. For some
>   reason if I switched the sound to mono I was able to get the
>   microphone working.